# Неактивное поле, не через disabled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Требуется сделать неактивным `select` находящийся в форме. Если делать это через `disabled` тогда не выполняется запрос формы.

Comment: а через `readonly`? и отображать можно липовый элемент, а реальный (который на сервер передается) может быть доступным, но скрытым

Comment: `readonly` не работает с `select` (((    а с input работает

Comment: точно, ну тогда через липовый элемент, [здесь](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) подробнее описано

Comment: Ну это конечно хорошо. но может еще есть варианты?

Comment: как вариант, ещё можно перед отправкой формы ставить disbled в false скриптом.

Comment: Хорошее решение для не больших списков, делать `disabled` для не нужных `option`. Или сделать для всех `disabled` а у нужного его отменить и дать ему `selected`.  Пока это самый лучший и просто вариант для меня.

Comment: Alexander Igorevich  нужно чтобы пользователь не мог делать не чего со списком

Comment: пользователь при любом раскладе если захочет сможет изменить это значение, поэтому на клиенте можно использовать любой понравившийся вариант, а на стороне сервера всегда проверять полученное значение. И еще вопрос - раз нельзя менять, значит значение каким-то образом выставилось. Раз выставилось один раз, значит можно выставить и второй раз, т.е. на стороне сервера можно каким-то образом получить значение, которое было в select'е, а значит его передавать и не обязательно, т.е. можно disabled использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/c0kftrj2/

```html
<form action=https://yandex.ru/search/ target=_blank>
  <input type=hidden name=text value="Что-то">
  <select name=text disabled><option>Что-то</option></select>
  <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.disabled {
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

и скриптом

```
$("#youSelect").addClass('disabled')
```

Comment: Оригинально. Только pointer-events не везде работает.